# How to solve Laravel error - Class 'App\Mail\Verification' not found?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to preview mail (obviously to style it), which is in

```
/resources/views/emails/verification.blade.php
```

In the route file:

```
use App\Mail\verification;
Route::get('/email', function () {
    return new verification();
});
```

But when I go to the `localhost:8000/email` I get fatal error:

```
Class 'App\Mail\verification' not found
```

In VerificationMail.php class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class VerificationMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $verify_token;

    public function __construct($verify_token)
    {
        $this->verify_token = $verify_token;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.verification');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Varification model is in Mail folder? Also use lowercase for blade file name

Comment: @Ahsan, yes, it is. Thanks for advice, I changed to lowercase, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Hey @TømaInagamov. You should also add the code of your `Verification` class. That could contain the problem. Maybe your class name is wrong, or maybe the namespace is. Without seeing everything is harder for people to help you out.

Comment: Very nice! I think it's easier to spot the issue now ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your class name is `VerificationMail` and that's also the filename `VerificationMail.php`. So that's all good.

However, you are trying to initialize a class that just doesn't exist:

```
use App\Mail\verification;
Route::get('/email', function () {
    return new verification();
});
```

You can see the problem in the first line (`use App\Mail\verification;`). That should be

```
use App\Mail\VerificationMail;
Route::get('/email', function () {
    return new VerificationMail('your-testing-token');
});
```

Comment: Well, VerificationMail is a model, so I don't understand how I should see the preview of the mail. That's why I get `Too few arguments to function App\Mail\VerificationMail::__construct(), 0 passed`. I definitely must use this file: `/resources/views/emails/verification.blade.php`

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean by "VerificationMail" is a model. It is not. It's a class that extends Laravel's `Mailable`. Mailable, can be rendered the way you are trying to do, that's done on purpose to allow for easier debugging. The error you mentioned tells you whats going on. Your `VeriticationMail` class expects an argument (you can see that in your constructor): a token. I edited my answer to include a token you can use for the purpose of previewing your email. Hope that helps

Comment: Your VerificationMail class does the work of creating the mailable that you can reference. In the build function of this class you have `$this->markdown('emails.verification')`. The `emails.verification` is what is pointing to your `/emails/verification.blade.php` file. That is why all you need to do is return a new instance of your VerificationMail class.

Comment: @Nicolas, yeah, it's a class, my bad

Comment: @nickc, but it returns error - `Too few arguments to function App\Mail\VerificationMail::__construct(), 0 passed`. because in construct function I use argument, but I don't pass it

Comment: @TømaInagamov then you need to pass something to the constructor. If what gets passed is unimportant than I would just use @Nicolas code `return new VerificationMail('your-testing-token');` or pass null if that doesn't break anything on the markdown side

Comment: @nickc I thought it was illigal XD tnks